# TLS handshake fails when raft mode is enabled

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I had a running Hyperledger Fabric network with TLS Enabled and Kafka consensus. Now, I have been trying to move to Raft and I am always getting this message in the orderers: `TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=ÌP:PORT`. As I said, TLS was perfectly working before the changes.

Now I am going to show you what I do related to RAFT and TLS Connections. First of all, I modify the `configtx.yaml` file, exactly the section related to the Ordering Service.

**Section of configtx.yaml**

```
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: etcdraft
  Addresses:
  - orderer0.org1:7050
  - orderer0.org2:7050
  - orderer0.org3:7050
  EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
    - Host: orderer0.org1
      Port: 7050
      ClientTLSCert: /data/org1/orderers/orderer0/tls/client.crt
      ServerTLSCert: /data/org1/orderers/orderer0/tls/server.crt
    - Host: orderer0.org2
      Port: 7050
      ClientTLSCert: /data/org2/orderers/orderer0/tls/client.crt
      ServerTLSCert: /data/org2/orderers/orderer0/tls/server.crt
    - Host: orderer0.org3
      Port: 7050
      ClientTLSCert: /data/org3/orderers/orderer0/tls/client.crt
      ServerTLSCert: /data/org3/orderers/orderer0/tls/server.crt
  Organizations:
  - *org1
  - *org2
  - *org3
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *OrdererCapabilities
```

As can be seen, TLS Client and Server certs from every organizaion orderer are required, so I generate them in each orderer container and upload it to a MinIO server I use to share.

```sh
echo "[INFO] Generating Client TLS Key and Certificate..."
fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL} -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts ${ORDERER_HOST}

echo "[INFO] Uploading Client TLS Certificate to Minio"
python3 /scripts/minio_upload.py --url ${STORAGE_URL} --access-key ${STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY} --secret-key ${STORAGE_SECRET_KEY} --bucket-name ${ORG} --local-path ${ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE} --remote-path orderers/${ORDERER_NAME}/tls/$(basename ${ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE})
echo "[INFO] Client TLS Certificate uploaded"
```

```sh
echo "[INFO] Enrolling orderer..."
fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL} -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts ${ORDERER_HOST}

echo "[INFO] Uploading Server TLS Certificate to Minio"
python3 /scripts/minio_upload.py --url ${STORAGE_URL} --access-key ${STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY} --secret-key ${STORAGE_SECRET_KEY} --bucket-name ${ORG} --local-path ${ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE} --remote-path orderers/${ORDERER_NAME}/tls/$(basename ${ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE})
echo "[INFO] Server TLS Certificate uploaded"
```

Once each orderer has generated and uploaded its certificates I run a new container, which I call `genesis`, where I download `configtx.yaml`, all the orderers certs (to the paths defined in `configtx.yaml`) and other things to generate genesis block, channel tx and anchor peer updates. After that, in each orderer, I also download all the orderers certs (do not know if this is required) to the same paths and, of course, copy the genesis block.

In all the orderers I have set to `true` ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED and ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED. As an instance, this is the TLS Configuration of `orderer0.org1`.

```
env:
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE
  value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED
  value: "false"
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE  # This is exposed for TLS connections
  value: /shared-storage/tls/orderer0/client.crt
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE  # This is exposed for TLS connections
  value: /shared-storage/tls/orderer0/client.key
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS  # Has to be the same that FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES
  value: '[/shared-storage/org1/ca-chain.pem]'
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
  value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS  # Has to be the same that FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES
  value: '[/shared-storage/org1/ca-chain.pem]'
```

What am I missing? Where is the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

You are missing these environment variables for your orderer:

```
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/shared-storage/tls/orderer0/client.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/shared-storage/tls/orderer0/client.key
      # I find strange you use org1 CA in your conf, but I trust you...
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/shared-storage/org1/ca-chain.pem]
```

Comment: Let's see. If I want to disable Kafka and run Raft, why do I want to set Kafka variables? It makes no sense.

Comment: Ok. Do not worry. Now we are talking. What I see is that I have to use _CLUSTER_ in addition to _TLS_ when using RAFT. Also, each one of my organizations have its own CA and, as orderers did not connected to themselves, I just used as CA the orderer CA, but I think I have to include all CAs: `- ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/shared-storage/org2/ca-chain.pem, /shared-storage/org1/ca-chain.pem, /shared-storage/org3/ca-chain.pem]`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Also, do you know if I need to download all the orderers ceritifcates in each orderer or they are included in the genesis block?

Comment: `ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS` must include the CA certificate chains of all organizations which have orderer nodes, so all orderers must include them in their volumes (or configmaps or whatever you are using). Not enough with the genesis block.

Comment: Commas, no spaces.

Comment: `ClientTLSCert` and `ServerTLSCert`, like `MSPDir`, it is used during the genesis block generation via `configtxgen` and makes reference to the location relative to the `configtx.yaml` file (if not absolute). It embeds the certificates in the genesis block itself, so they dont need to be included later with that purpose.

Comment: My god. It works. I have it hardcoded as hell but it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The error message 'first record does not look like a TLS handshake' indicates that you have a 'client' trying to open a plain (i.e. non-TLS) connection. Make sure all connections are set up to use TLS in all kind of 'clients' (i.e. other orderers, peers, client applications using sdk, etc.).

Comment: As I said, TLS was working before moving to RAFT, so I do not touched anything in the peers/client applications. I do not think it is the problem